# How mongoDB aggregation query can be convert in to Java DBObject?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have problem find "and","or" logical operation (agrregation framework) in java

This code works fine with single variable
DBObject match=new BasicDBObject("$match",new BasicDBObject("item","a"));
but i want match more than one variable

Please somebody expalin how i can write "and" /"or" in this query .

Comment: please post your code so that we can provide help.

Comment: db.temp2.aggregate([ { $match:{$or:[ { ITEMTYPE: 'like' },{ ITEMTYPE: 'post' }]}},{$group : {_id :{ cust_id2:"$POSTDBID"}, numberofPostID : {$sum : 1}}},{ $sort: { numberofPostID: -1 } },{ $limit : 5 }]);

Comment: @philip would please convert this query to java..

Comment: @user35662 may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629010/mongo-group-by-query-convert-into-java

Comment: @yogesh there is nothing explaination about multiple field with "$match"

Comment: @ Thanks all. Here is good post for this solution                                                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732557/mongodb-aggregration-framework-and-java-driver-making-or-condtion-work

Answer (score 0):

When you query for multiple values of the same field, it's simpler to use $in instead of $or.  Here's your example translated into Java using $in:

```
new BasicDBObject("ITEMTYPE", new BasicDBObject("$in", Arrays.asList("like", "post")))
```

Or using the QueryBuilder:

```
QueryBuilder.start("ITEMTYPE").in(Arrays.asList("like", "post")).get()
```